# How to mount a windows partition in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, mount

I am a new user to Ubuntu.I don't have much system knowledge.
I have upgraded 14.04 to 16.04 in my laptop.Earlier I had solved the problem by modifying fstab. Now it is not working. Due to this I am not able to use any of the media players like Banshee.File type is NTFS.I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type

```
 sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

XY: label...eg sda7

For permanent solution: turn off hibernation(in windows)

Open command prompt as administrator and type

```
 powercfg -h off
```

If problem occurs again after next bootup

Open run prompt from start menu

```
 1. Type and Start msconfig.exe 
 2. On the general tab select "Selective startup" and uncheck "Load startup items".
 3. On the services tab unselect all first
 4. Runt the command "powercfg -h off" to turn off hibernation.
 5. Reboot
 6. If hibernation is still deactivated start msconfig.exe again and activate half of the services.
 7. Repeat 5 and 6 until you find the service causing hibernation to be turned back on       (don't forget to do step 4 if it is activated again).
```

Comment: Thank you. But how to do it on booting?

Comment: Turn of hibernation from power settings in windows

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Check edit in answer...and if it helps.. consider accepting as solution :) gud luck

Comment: How to switch to administrator in windows 7

Comment: Press superkey(windows logo) + 'X' key ... new menu will appear select command prompt(admin)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46896/discussion-between-rajesh-krishnan-and-minigeek).

Comment: I got an exam tomorrow...google how to turn off hibernation in windows..and u will Find many solutions (4 to5 ways)...else ping here tomorrow